# Java Regex multi delimiter split in order

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am trying to split a string having multi-delimiters in it but want to first check if the string satisfies the regex and then split based on it.
Example:-
The testString will contain ://,:,@,:,/ these characters in specific order and I need to first check if the given string satisfies the pattern or not and if satisfy then split it. The string other characters can also contain these in it but I need to split based on order of these ://,:,@,:,/

```
String testString = "aman://jaspreet:raman!@127.0.0.1:5031/test";
String[]tokens = testString.split("://|\\:|@|\\:|\\/");
for(String s:tokens) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Here above I have tried the regex to split but it doesn't split by checking in order. It just checks if any given regex character exists in string or not and then splits based on it.

Comment: yes @Abra, exactly what I am trying to do. But the tricky part is jaspreet and raman here is username and password which can also have special characters based on which I am splitting. So the order of regex pattern is important for split.

Comment: No, if username contains single colon character (:) as jasp:reet and password is raman, the split should give jasp and reet:raman as we would be splitting with first single colon character (:) after (://).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you first validate the pattern, then you shouldn't do `split()` after. Use *capturing groups* to gather the data you already validated.

E.g. in a simple case, `foo@bar`, with separator `@`, you would validate with `^([^@]+)@(.+)$`, i.e. match and capture text up to `@`, match but don't capture the `@`, then match and capture the rest:

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([^@]+)@(.+)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher("foo@bar");
if (! m.matches()) {
    // invalid data
} else {
    String a = m.group(1); // a = "foo"
    String b = m.group(2); // b = "bar"
    // use a and b here
}
```

For the matching in the question, a lenient pattern could be:

```regex
^(.*?)://(.*?):(.*?)@(.*?):(.*?)/(.*)$
```

You would then use code above, but with:

```java
    String scheme   = m.group(1); // "aman"
    String user     = m.group(2); // "jaspreet"
    String password = m.group(3); // "raman!"
    String host     = m.group(4); // "127.0.0.1"
    String port     = m.group(5); // "5031"
    String path     = m.group(6); // "test"
```

For a stricter matching, replace `.*?` with a pattern that only matches allowed characters, e.g. `[^:]+` if it cannot be empty and cannot contain colons.

Alternatively, you could just use the [`URI`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class to parse the URL string.

```java
String testString = "aman://jaspreet:raman!@127.0.0.1:5031/test";
URI uri = URI.create(testString);

String scheme   = uri.getScheme();   // "aman"
String userInfo = uri.getUserInfo(); // "jaspreet:raman!"
String host     = uri.getHost();     // "127.0.0.1"
String port     = uri.getPort();     // "5031"
String path     = uri.getPath();     // "test"
```

Comment: Thanks @Andreas. I found URI class just before reading your answer. Anyways thanks a lot for great explanation. Accepted your answer.